# Can we access list custom settings in javascript inside the VF page?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I tried to access list custom setting inside visualforce page javascript. But I'm not able to save the changes I made, it is giving error as **"Error: Field FilterSetting__c does not exist. Check spelling"**

```
var cs = "{!$Setup.FilterSetting__c.Value__c}";
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Hierarchy Custom Settings can be directly accessed from Visualforce. For list custom settings, you will have to use Apex.

```
public String fsValue {get; set;}
...
FilterSetting__c fs = FilterSetting__c.getValues(data_set_name);
fsValue = fs.Value__c;
...
```